# How to get dynamic results of the values in three InputFields

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

I have three `InputField`-s which have no initial value. I would like all `InputFields` to have a value in descending order and for each  `InputField`, a "right" and "wrong" symbol should be displayed as soon as some value is entered in any of these `InputFields`.

The user can enter his first value, say 89 in any of the `InputField` between 100 and 0. It will always show "right" symbol as all other `InputField`-s are empty. If he choose the next `InputField` to be filled in the right hand side of the previous `InputField`, then that value should be between 89 and 0 else it should show wrong dynamically. And If he chooses some other `InputField` to be filled in the left hand side of the first `InputField`, then that value should be between 100 and 89 else it is wrong.

[image]

I faced the problem when I skipped the first `InputField` and entered 76 in the second `InputField`. It looked alright but as soon as I entered 89 in the third `InputField`, both were shown as wrong.

```
logicalInputField[i_, numberOfFields_, tx_, symbol_, upperLimit_, 
lowerLimit_, noValue_, right_, wrong_] :=
   (txtx = tx; sysy = symbol; upup = upperLimit;lolo = lowerLimit; nono = noValue; riri    = right; wrwr = wrong; 
Column[{InputField[Dynamic[txtx[[i]]], Number, FieldSize -> 3, 
   Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ContinuousAction -> True],
  ( Dynamic[(  If[txtx[[i]] == Null,    (txtx[[i]] = ""; sysy[[i]] = noValue), (sysy[[i]] = right)    ];        
   For[j = i - 1, j >= 1, j--, If[txtx[[j]] != "", (upup[[i]] = txtx[[j]]; Break[];), 
       ""]];  
    For[k = i + 1, k <= numberOfFields, k++,            
     If[txtx[[k]] != "", (lolo[[i]] = txtx[[k]]; Break[];), 
       ""]];                                         
 If[txtx[[i]] >= lolo[[i]],           
                                                (sysy[[i]] = 
         right;), (sysy[[i]] = wrong;)   ];
        If[lolo < txtx[[i]] <= upup[[i]],    
                                                (sysy[[i]] = 
         right;), (sysy[[i]] = wrong;) ];

     sysy[[i]] )    ])   }]) ;                                              


  DynamicModule[{s = {}, enterValue = "ENTER", correct = "RIGHT", incorrect = "WRONG"}, For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,  DynamicModule[{i = i},
  AppendTo[s, logicalInputField[i, 3, {"", "", ""}, {enterValue, enterValue, enterValue}, {100, 100,
   100}, {0, 0, 0}, enterValue, correct, incorrect]]] ];
      Panel[ Row[s, Spacer[0]]]]
```

Comment: Consider proving an example of the problem you are facing. Without the code that's causing the problem, it's very difficult to figure out what could be causing it.

Comment: @jVincent: I have added the code.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is it's due to the "direction" you're comparing the numbers in, though honestly I'm having trouble reading your code. Here's the general approach I would use for doing something like this:

```
descending[numberOfFields_] := DynamicModule[{
    numbers = {Infinity} ~Join~ ConstantArray[100, numberOfFields]},

   Grid[Table[
     {DynamicModule[{is = i}, Checkbox[Dynamic[numbers[[is]] < numbers[[is - 1]]], Enabled -> False]],
      DynamicModule[{is = i}, InputField[Dynamic[numbers[[is]]]]]},
     {i, 2, numberOfFields + 1, 1}]]
   ];

descending[3]
```

[image: example output]

General note: You can use Tab to cycle through inputs and update Dynamic elements.

Answer (score 3):

I took a different approach, using the second argument of `Dynamic`, and generalized it to any number of `InputField`s. The list of input values is stored in `list`, their evaluations (`eval`) to `"Right"`, `"Wrong"` or `"Enter"` (indeterminate) is calculated on the fly by comparing from right to left. This means that entering a nonnumerical value in the 2nd position makes the test to fall back to `"Enter"` for the next entries to the right, as they cannot be compared to the entry at position 2. This also causes that any entry after a `"Wrong"` entry will be evaluated to `"Wrong"`.

```
n = 5;(*number of InputFields*)
list = Array["" &, {n}];(*user input values*)
eval = Array["Enter" &, {n}];(*"Enter","Right" or "Wrong"*)

Panel@Dynamic[Grid@{
    InputField[Dynamic[list[[#]], Function[{$x}, list[[#]] = $x;
         eval = 
          If[NumberQ@list[[#]], 
             If[Greater @@ Take[list, #], "Rigth", "Wrong", "Enter"], 
             "Enter"] & /@ Range@n]], Number, FieldSize -> 3, 
       ContinuousAction -> True] & /@ Range@n,
    eval
    }, TrackedSymbols :> {eval}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Updated**

As OP has further specified the problem, here is an evolved version, that always accepts the first input (if it is a number) regardless of position, and checks successive inputs against their neighbours **and** also rechecks the full `eval` list, so that later corrections at e.g. the left side could render previously wrong results good:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also, comparison always starts from left, so the following can be expected:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since `ContinuousAction` won't work seamlessly (`InputField`s keeps loosing focus during typing) if the whole `Grid` is wrapped in `Dynamic[..., TrackedSymbols :> {eval}]`, I split the `Grid` to two, and resized them with `ItemSize`.

```
n = 5; (* number of InputFields *)
neighbours = {};
list = Array["" &, {n}];(* user input values *)

{right, wrong, enter} = {Checkbox@True, Checkbox[Null, {True, False}], Checkbox@False};
eval = Array[enter &, {n}];(* list to store enter/right/wrong data *)

Panel@Column@{
   Grid[{
     InputField[Dynamic[list[[#]], Function[{$x},
          list[[#]] = $x;
          neighbours = 
           DeleteCases[Take[list, {Max[1, # - 1], Min[n, # + 1]}], ""];

          (* check whether the actual field in focus has correct value or not *)           
          eval[[#]] = If[And @@ (NumberQ /@ neighbours), 
            If[Greater @@ neighbours, right, wrong], right, enter];

          (* update all other eval fields according to the new value of the focus field *)
          eval = If[NumberQ@list[[#]], 
              If[Greater @@ DeleteCases[Take[list, #], ""], right, wrong], enter] & /@ Range@n;
          ]], Number, FieldSize -> 3, ContinuousAction -> True] & /@ Range@n
     }, ItemSize -> 4],
   Dynamic@Grid[{eval}, ItemSize -> 4]
   }
```

Comment: This is something different from what I am looking. I have edited my question for better understanding.

Comment: @Jennifer Please check edit.